# Does the Lesser Beast Totem upscale to 1d8 claw damage for large creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, barbarian, creature-size, natural-weapon

I have a half-giant barbarian (built from the Advanced Races Guide). I've reached 2nd level and have taken the [Lesser Beast Totem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/beast-totem-lesser-su) rage power.

I've noticed that the claws only mention scaling down from the medium 1d6 damage to the small 1d4 damage. Considering I'm large, does it upscale to the large 1d8 damage?

Answer (score 5):

The listing in the description is just there so that in the most common cases (Small and Medium) you don’t have to go look up the [Natural Attacks by Size Table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks).

A weapon that deals 1d6 when Medium deals 1d8 when Large, so yes, your claws deal 1d8. The linked table can be used to scale up or down any natural weapon (and its more-or-less identical to a similar table for manufactured weapons).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say its the GM's decision.  The claws technically list 1d6 damage, which is not what the [Natural Attacks by Size Table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks) lists for medium size creatures.  Therefore the size chart doesn't REALLY apply.  However, I would 100% expect the GM to scale damage with the size.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Note that the table you linked to "lists *some of the most common types* of natural attacks and their classifications." The table in the FAQ below it should be used for size changes in general.